# ZSH not wrapping lines (Screen IOS)

Tags: mac, display, zsh

zsh 4.3.9 (i386-apple-darwin10.0)
inside Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06
inside Termianl Version 2.1.1 (273)

I've had this problem once or twice. Basically, output from programs stopps wrapping.

While coding in ruby, I often inspect elements as I go inside tests.  However, when this problem occurs, the output doesn't wrap.

The end of the line would just look like:

```
 business_id: 66, published: nil, recind>
```

instead of

```
 business_id: 66, published: nil, recinded_at: [sometime], [lots more properties over here]
```